# WordPress custom post title to be added automatically as a tag

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a question. I want to add a tag automatically on my posts but I don't know how to do it. i want to add post Title before tag but how i can do that?

```
   function set_archive_tag_on_publish($post_id,$post) {
  if ($post->post_type == 'movies'
    && $post->post_status == 'publish') {
      wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'tag1, tag2, tag3', true );
    }
  }
add_action('save_post','set_archive_tag_on_publish');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update as of 2020

| Version | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `5.5.0` | Introduced `default_term` argument. |

Since Wordpress [version 5.5.0](https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-5-5/#more-changes-for-developers) release, you're now able to specify a default term when registering a new custom taxonomy using the very handy [`default_term` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters).

```php
$args = [
    /...
    'default_term' => [ //(string|array) Default term to be used for the taxonomy.
        'name' => 'Potato', //(string) Name of default term.
        'slug' => 'potato', //(string) Slug for default term.
        'description' => 'You can spend the night inside a potato, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2mj-7-Zklw', //(string) Description for default term.
    ],
    /...
];
```